# NID in new created node title

Tags: 7

I don't like second `node_save`. But I need `nid` for title.

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'bill';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->uid = $user->uid;
$node->field_body['und'][0]['value'] = $bodytxt;
$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);

$node->title = 'Bill # '.$node->nid;
node_save($node);
```

Is there more elegant way?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there more elegant way?

Not really - the NID doesn't exist until the node has been saved the first time, so there is no way around this if you want to save the node title.

However, you could just add the NID to the title when the node is loaded:

```
function hook_node_load(&$nodes, $types)
{
  foreach($nodes as $node)
  {
    if($node->type == 'my_type')
    {
      $nodes[$node->nid]->title = '#Bill ' . $node->nid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: True, but if they are autonaming these lets say, for a Q&A, and the title is "Question", they may want NID in the title for URL and admin management purposes. Just a thought. However if this is for an invoice manager, then invoice number should be a field IMO.